# Take data from dataframe and pass to a method for its function and return another dataframe with new column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

[image]

I would like to pass each of the row into the function and return a new dataframe with extra column named "kilometer".

My data name is "train".

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

def find_distance(train):
    # approximate radius of earth in km
    R = 6373.0

    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lon1 = radians(lon1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)
    lon2 = radians(lon2)

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    distance = R * c
    return distance
```

How can I have another dataframe that has "Kilometer" which is the return value of distance?

I can load any of the series such as train.pickup_longitude.

Answer (score 0):

Use .apply()

```
train['kilometer'] = train.apply(find_distance,axis=1)
```

You'll need to align your column names and function names.